# How to describe "reduce" function with interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript, interface, reduce

How to describe "reduce" function with interface in typescript? 
[image]

Comment: Please post code not pictures. It is simpler to figure out what is happening if I have a full working sample I can copy paste rather then a picture of half a function

Answer (score 1):

```
// if no initialValue is passed
reduce(callbackfn: (previousValue: T, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => T): T;
// if initialValue is passed
reduce(callbackfn: (previousValue: T, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => T, initialValue: T): T;
```